# Using Chrome instead of Internet Explorer in Webbrowser

Tags: vb.net

Is there any way to use Chrome instead of Internet Explorer 
I've found a way to make webbrowser uses the latest Internet Explorer but still the website i want to visit doesn't support IE .... i even tried in Internet Explorer latest and it doesn't work like it does in Google Chrome !

Comment: https://cefsharp.github.io/

Comment: WebBrowser intentionally lies to the web site about the IE version it supports, picking a very low number to be as compatible as possible.  But web sites are not compatible anymore.  That is going to happen to that Chrome version you hard-bake in as well some day, some day soon given the very rapid version increases.  Google FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION

Answer (score 0):

You can get an open source API here: http://webkitdotnet.sourceforge.net/

Comment: WebKit is even worse than the IE .... i just tried it and it's not even working on the website i want ...